# Thread message queue blocking

Tags: ffmpeg

Using this command:

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -f -y -rtbufsize 100M -f gdigrab -t 00:00:30 -framerate 30 -probesize 10M -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -r 30 -preset fast -tune zerolatency -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p "XXXXXX"
...
[dshow @ 05bdd9c0] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[gdigrab @ 05c51800] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
```

Above are the messages I got. How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `-thread_queue_size` before each `-i` and increase the value until the message goes away:

```
ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -thread_queue_size 512 -i audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -f -rtbufsize 100M -f gdigrab -t 00:00:30 -framerate 30 -probesize 10M -draw_mouse 1 -thread_queue_size 512 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -preset fast -tune zerolatency -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p "XXXXXX"
```

Comment: The Thread message was not showing now after recording while playing the video after some time it's stuck,it doesnt recorded a whloe video.